# Regex stop capturing anything if string ends with specific sequence

Tags: regex

I'm having a hard time getting a regex to do what I need.

This is the regex that I came up with:

```
(^([A-Z0-9]{3}[WTL])(TB)?(?!LG))
```

This is what I need it to do:
Capture any 3 char/number sequence from the beginning like `ABC` or `A2C` or `XYZ`
Continue to capture `W`, `T` or `L`
Optionally capture if following sequence is `TB`
Now if the current capture includes `LG` after `W`, `T`, `L`  or after `TB`  , break the whole capture and return nothing.

The last part with `LG` is what I'm having problems with.

Here are some examples strings that I'm working with
The | notes the spot up until I need the capture but it is not included in the original strings.

Should capture

```
ABCWTB|12345
ABCLTB|12345
FGHT|12345
AAAW|12345
B2BL|12345
XYZTTB|345345
```

Should not capture anything (these work)

```
ABCLLG12345
FGHTLG12345
X2ZWLG12345
```

Should not capture anything (these don't work)

```
ABCWTBLG12345
XYZTTBLG345345
F2HLTBLG345345
```

My current regex works for strings that don't have the optional `TB` but if that is present, it matches the first 4 chars. What do I need to do to break capturing if `LG` is present after the optional `TB`
I tried so many things to get this working. Any help with a little explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the optional pattern into the negative lookahead and move the lookahead before the optional pattern:

```
^([A-Z0-9]{3}[WTL])(?!(?:TB)?LG)(TB)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W6R07W/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z0-9]{3}` - three uppercase letters or digits
- `[WTL]` - `W`/`T`/`L`
- `(?!(?:TB)?LG)(TB)?` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `TBLG` or `LG` immediately to the right of the current location
- `(TB)?` - an optional `TB` char sequence.

If your regex flavor supports possessive quantifiers, you can use `^([A-Z0-9]{3}[WTL])(TB)?+(?!LG)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W6R07W/3). Or, an atomic group: `^([A-Z0-9]{3}[WTL])(?>(TB)?)(?!LG)`.